# Linux setcap: fatal error:invalid argument Note <filename> must be a regular (non-symlink) file

Tags: linux, kibana, symlink, linux-capabilities

My linux is CentOS7.

When I run Elastic Beats-Auditbeat with non-root user,
It shows this error:

```
ERROR   instance/beat.go:877    Exiting: 1 error: 1 error: failed to create audit client: failed to get audit status: operation not permitted
Exiting: 1 error: 1 error: failed to create audit client: failed to get audit status: operation not permitted`
```

So I check the capability which the process lacked with this command

**strace ./auditbeat -c 1 localhost 2>&1 | grep EPERM** and it shows:

```
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 3, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT|EPOLLRDHUP|EPOLLET, {u32=66785192, u64=140471267168168}}) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, 3, {0, {u32=0, u64=0}}) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

I found the lacked capability is **CAP_BLOCK_SUSPEND** by this [doc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).

But when I run command **setcap cap_block_suspend=ep auditbeat** it shows:

```
fatal error: Invalid argument
usage: setcap [-q] [-v] (-r|-|<caps>) <filename> [ ... (-r|-|<capsN>) <filenameN> ]

Note <filename> must be a regular (non-symlink) file.
```

Whereas the auditbeat is just a **regular file**:

```
[usr@linuxhost auditbeat-7.2.0-linux-x86_64]$ stat auditbeat
File: ‘auditbeat’
Size: 70418699        Blocks: 137544     IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: pasef/17006b   Inode: 410084318   Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1004/  usr  )   Gid: ( 1004/  usr  )
Access: 2019-08- 0:39:29.160306947 +000
Modify: 2019-06-20 23:04:01.000000000 +000
Change: 2019-08- 0:39:06.226434256 +000
Birth: -
```

How could I solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Grafana on Ubuntu. Will report back if I find anything.

Comment: Looks like this is a different issue but with a similar symptom. Nonetheless, as promised, here are my findings. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62088605/how-do-you-setcap-in-ubuntu-16-04-6-to-allow-grafana-to-bind-to-port-80/62088606#62088606

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. My issue happened because the file I was working with was in a mounted filesystem. I solved it by copying the file to /tmp, running setcap on the /tmp file, then creating a symlink from /tmp back to the original location.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue, seem the first parameter was not recognized by setcap. According to https://linux.die.net/man/3/cap_from_text
I changed the command from to `setcap "all=ep" /usr/bin/perf`, the issue was gone