# How do you setcap in Ubuntu 16.04.6 to allow Grafana to bind to port 80?

Tags: ubuntu, grafana

The [Grafana config docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/configuration/) state that "To use port 80 you need to ... give the Grafana binary permission." When I run the instructed command

```
sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/sbin/grafana-server
```

I get

```
Failed to set capabilities on file `/usr/sbin/grafana-server' (Invalid argument)
The value of the capability argument is not permitted for a file. Or the file is not a regular (non-symlink) file
```

When I run

```
sudo setcap ‘cap_net_bind_service=+ep’ /usr/sbin/grafana-server
```

I get

```
fatal error: Invalid argument
usage: setcap [-q] [-v] (-r|-|<caps>) <filename> [ ... (-r|-|<capsN>) <filenameN> ]

 Note <filename> must be a regular (non-symlink) file.
```

How do I allow Grafana to bind to port 80?

Answer (score 0):

When one follows the "[Install from APT repository](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/debian/#install-from-apt-repository)" instructions, I notice that `/usr/sbin/` contains a file called `grafana` but not one named `grafana-server`. I changed the command to

```
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /usr/sbin/grafana
```

set port 80 in `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini`

```
# The HTTP port  to use
http_port = 80
```

then started the server again,

```
sudo systemctl start grafana-server
```

and it works fine. Perhaps this is a recent change that is awaiting an update in the Grafana docs. Alternatively, follow the "[Install .deb package](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/debian/#install-deb-package)" instrucitons.